# Magento - Custom model one to many relationship

Tags: magento, module, one-to-many

I'm writing a custom module for Magento and I need to implement a one-to-many relationship between two tables.

The easyest solution is to create one model for each table and save data separately, but I think this approach has some limitations (I prefer saving data in one single transaction instead of two, I want to load the combined data when I load the collection, ecc).

What is the best way to handle this kind of situation? Is it possible to have one model class that retrieves data from multiple tables?

Thank you

Comment: One model can only allow one table collection. So, you need to have to models, later on which you can join them to fetch your combined data.

Comment: @KalpeshMehta Generally the case, but not entirely correct. Many collections are built from multiple tables with data joined in. See my answer below.

Answer (score 4):

If the 1-n relationship is strictly a data construct rather than an entity construct, then there is no need for a full ORM representation for the adjacent table.

It's often good to find inspiration and examples in the core code, so please refer to the `cms/page` and `cms/block` entities, particularly to their resource models. Take the [`Mage_Cms_Model_Resource_Page::_getLoadSelect()`](https://github.com/LokeyCoding/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Model/Resource/Page.php#L196) method as an example, as this method is called by the resource model to load data:

```
protected function _getLoadSelect($field, $value, $object)
{
    $select = parent::_getLoadSelect($field, $value, $object);

    $storeId = $object->getStoreId();
    if ($storeId) {
        $select->join(
                    array('cps' => $this->getTable('cms/page_store')),
                    $this->getMainTable().'.page_id = `cps`.page_id'
                )
                ->where('is_active=1 AND `cps`.store_id IN (' . Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID . ', ?) ', $storeId)
                ->order('store_id DESC')
                ->limit(1);
    }
    return $select;
}
```

Note the join, and note that they have one entity table each (`cms_page` and `cms_block`) respectively - this is what the ORM expects, by the way - but there are additional tables which contain cms-entity-to-store data. (`cms_page_store` and `cms_block_store`). The records in these latter two tables are not represented by their own ORM classes, rather, they are updated, removed, or joined for loads by the `cms/page` and `cms/block` models' resource classes.

Again, the deciding factor on whether to handle the SQL through designated ORM classes comes from the business domain - if the records in the 'many' tables represent things which need presentation or complex representation in your business domain, access them through ORM.

Comment: nice to know that @benmarks . Btw do you know why it handles insert / update to cms_page_store in after save but for deletion, it put the code in beforedelete (though I don't think it will affect the result). Sorry if it is a bit off the topic

Comment: @ivantedja In the case of `_afterSave()` it has to do with having the CMS entity (id) available for the entity-to-store foreign key. For the `_beforeDelete()` implementation, I'm not sure, as deleting the `cms_block` entity data would delete the `cms_block_store` data based on the foreign key constraint. This was added in CE1.6 and might be related to EE indirectly, but I'm not sure. It's a fair question which is germaine.